# I am needing to sort data from a large csv file in python and need help splitting the data into parts to be able to sort the information

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a really large csv file that contains countries, abbreviations, years, and other data. I need to split this into at least 4 parts in order to sort through it and find information based off of the different parts. But I am having troubles figuring out how to divide them into parts.
If someone could help me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Here is what I have right now:

Can anyone help me understand how to split parts so I can sort them out with a user input for a project. I have this:

```
 for line in life_expectancy:
    reader_parts = line.split(",")
    country = reader_parts[0]
    abv = reader_parts[1]
    year = int(reader_parts[2])
    expectancy = float(reader_parts[3])
```

Comment: Use `csv` library.

Comment: *I need to split this into at least 4 parts in order to sort through it*. Why? How did you come up with number 4? What issue do you have with your code?

Comment: You can use panda library to split data into differents parts `chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=size)` doc --> [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: For sorting a large CSV, you could try a command-line tool called [csvsort](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/2_examining_the_data.html#csvsort-order-matters). It's more memory-efficient and will let you choose which column to sort by.

Comment: I don't think they need to split the file into 4 parts by rows, I think they just have rows with 4 columns.

Comment: How large is large? How do you want to sort the data? Can you provide some example data for us?

Comment: It has every country and information from those countries since the year 1950. Country, abbreviation, year, and life expectancy.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)
It enables you to deal with large files while avoiding copying the whole file into memory at once.

Here is your code snippet:

```
import fileinput
with fileinput.input('path-to-the-life-expectancy-file', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        reader_parts = line.split(",")
        country = reader_parts[0]
        abv = reader_parts[1]
        year = int(reader_parts[2])
        expectancy = float(reader_parts[3])
```

Comment: I will try this and see if this works for what I am trying to do. I will let you know.

Comment: What's the advantage over the simpler `with open('path-to-the-life-expectancy-file', encoding="utf-8") as f:`?

Comment: @KellyBundy, it is intended to deal with large files. It avoids copying the whole file into the system's memory at once that might cause breaking it.

Comment: I asked for an advantage over `open()`. That one likewise doesn't read the whole file into memory at once, so that's not an advantage. So what's an actual advantage?

Comment: True. Not a huge advantage over `open()`. The only advantage is that it is designed to iterate over lines from multiple input files.